# Automating react native apps

Tags: android, ios, react-native, app-store-connect, google-developers-console

I have 1 React native webview app.

I would like to produce X amount of WebView apps with that 1 app. Everything will be the same apart from the initial brand url and brand logos.

So i would like to write a script that calls `react-native new brandName` and then copies all the files from the first react native app with the correct brand and brandURL variables. (I think this is possible ?)

Secondly i would like to automate the App creation on iTunes Connect/Google Play with all relevant certificates/profiles. (is there a way to create an app in itunes connect from command line?)

And finally push to itunes/google

What does everyone think, is this realistic?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) is what you want.

Comment: I looked into fastlane, as far as im aware it only supports packaging up and releasing from the command line. Does it also support creating the app within itunes connect?

Comment: For that process, I would make a script that clone a project "boilerplate" from some source and then change variables to terminal using something like "sed".

First option)

1. clone from git
2. remove .git directory
3. Massive replacement of the project name in the source files. Using sed.
4. git init


Second option)
1. rsync a boilerplate directory
2. Massive replacement of the project name in the source files. Using sed.
3. git init

Comment: Cheers that automates the creation... but again my issue is creating a new app in itunes connect.. is this possible to do without going through the UI on https://itunesconnect.apple.com/