# Automating the building of react native apps with gitlab

Tags: react-native, automation, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

So far, I mainly used expo to preview my React Native app(s), and let others do the building (e.g. the APK for Android). Now, I want to do it myself and directly automatize this using gitlab.

I have to confess that I am not familiar with gitlab CI (yet), but I have experience with other CI-tools like Jenkins or Azure DevOps.
So far, I have a Ubuntu-server hosting my GIT-repo and I would go for installing gitlab on that machine, but how do I proceed now?

Here on Stackoverflow I found a couple questions on the topic of "React Native CI", which are not helping me much: One question is closed, the others are tackling only part of the challenge:

- [Automating react native apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43915845/8330162)
- [React-native: what automation CI tool is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40427725/8330162)
- [Continuous Integration with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29381230/8330162)

This are aside, I also found

- A 2018 tutorial called *[Automate React Native Builds With Gitlab CI](https://hybridheroes.de/blog/2018-09-24-react-native-gitlab-ci/)* which seem to use Expo (which I heard is not strictly necessary).
- [GitLab CI/CD for a React Native App](https://medium.com/swlh/gitlab-ci-cd-for-a-react-native-app-1746d994506e) suggests a docker-based architecture which I do not want to have.
- [How to build and publish your React Native Android applications using GitLab CI](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/community-writers/-/issues/12) is rather rudimentary.

**Could someone please give me a top-level summary which minimal architectural components I need to have?**

Comment: Here is a good article to help you: https://medium.com/@iampravikant/ci-cd-pipeline-for-react-native-project-in-jenkins-from-bitbucket-396fa29f8dc5